# Require field validator disappear because of auto post of drop down

Tags: asp.net

here is issue with my require filed validator , here i use one drop down box for select time with associated with require field validator in my drop down there are 1-24 hour time  and Select time with first index. in my page in drop down for time selection is necessary if user  select the time then again goes  the initial value of first index or select time option that time require field validator work and disappear immediately because of partial post back or auto post back of drop down.i have also use Update panel. i want that whenever user does not select time or choos select time option that time require field validator prompt user for select time. until user does not select time it cant process further.

```
<div class="loginBox">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" Text="Date & Time:" CssClass="jobTitle"   AssociatedControlID="txtDate"
                    runat="server"></asp:Label>                    
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTime"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTime_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTime" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddlTime"
                    Text="Select Time" ErrorMessage="Select Time" InitialValue="-1" CssClass="ErrMsg"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
```

Comment: set CausesValidation property to true. like-CausesValidation='true' and then check..

Comment: thanks  rr_only4you,i have already applied this property.i m also enable check box after selecting time after applied this property then this check box does not enable

Comment: any one have solution for this issue

Comment: Please verify you have put your code in if(!IsPostback){}

Comment: hi rr_only4you, ya i write my code inside this but this is aspx code u can put any where there is no option   if(!IsPostback){}

Comment: The validator disappears bcoz you have set autopostback property to true. set it to false and check if it works or not.

Comment: hi rr_only4you, i need it set autopost back try because after selected index change there another  drop down  is binding

Comment: set InitialValue="Select" and then check...

Comment: set to whatever is your value like  InitialValue="-Select-" and then check...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32543/discussion-between-sandeep-and-rr-only4you)